# Why isn't my navbar fixed in it's position?

Tags: html, css, scroll, navbar

I've made a diagonal scroll page but when I applied the plugin to make it scroll this way the navbar was not fixed anymore, plus my sections aren't centered, I mean they're displayed vertically instead of diagonally, I don't know how to display them that way, any solutions? My top priority is the navbar, but if I can fix both things in one question, even better. Thanks SO community!

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

body {
  background-color: #900c3f;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

img {
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: #ff5733;
}

.nav-links li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#F5F5F5, #F5F5F5);
  background-position: 0 100%;
  /*OR bottom left*/
  background-size: 0% 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-size 0.3s, background-position 0s 0.3s;
  /*change after the size immediately*/
}

.nav-links li a:hover {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  /*OR bottom right*/
  background-size: 100% 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/*.nav-links li a{
          display: inline-block;
        }

        .nav-links li a:after {
          content: '';
          width: 0;
          height: 5px;
          display: block;
          background: #F5F5F5;
          transition: 300ms;
          border-radius: 5px;
        } */

.nav-links li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 80%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  height: 92vh;
  top: 17vh;
  background-color: #ff5733;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 80%;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.nav-links li {
  opacity: 0;
}

.burger {
  display: block;
}


}
@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}
section h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Section Images */
section#home {
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bZZp1PmHI0E/1600x900') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
section#portfolio {
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/VRxo0yY-gyM/1600x900') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
section#submit {
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/K2tdx2mFDHc/1600x900') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
section#contact {
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/2aAHlfDOhJM/1600x900') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
section#about {
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo+Black&family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Subworld Productions</title>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">-->


<body data-0="transform:translateX(0%)" data-4000="transform:translateX(-300%)">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <img src="Graphic logo.png" alt="Subworld Productions">
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#submit">Submit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section id="home">
      <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="portfolio">
      <h1>PORTFOLIO PAGE</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="submit">
      <h1>SUBMIT PAGE</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="contact">
      <h1>CONTACT PAGE</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="about">
      <h1>ABOUT PAGE</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
  </header>
  <!-- <script src="javascript/app.js"></script>
  <script src="skrollr.js"></script>-->
  <script src="http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/dist/skrollr.min.js">
    skrollr.init();
  </script>
</body>
```

[image: scroll screenshot 1]

[image: scroll screenshot 2]

Comment: No way to answer this Q by screenshots + relative paths `css/styles.css` and `javascript/app.js`. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues with your css. The first is that you had multiple declarations for nav link attributes. I grouped them and adjusted them (more later) I also tidied your css to put your css in order: nav links first then nav links li then nav links li a etc, because css is read in that order. You had `display:flex;` and `position:absolute` in one css class - these conflict, and i removed the absolute positioning.

What was really throwing out your ul however, making the links non-viewable, was the translateX - translating your links by 100% was moving your links out of sight. I commented this out. As-is (now) your links display, animate on hover, and scroll-to the appropriate section when clicked. One more note: you had two semi-colons after the urls in your sections. I corrected this both in your posted code and snippet code.

Hope this helps

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

body {
  background-color: #900c3f;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

img {
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: #ff5733;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 80%;
  /*   position: absolute;
  right: 0px;*/
  height: 10vh;
  top: 17vh;
  background-color: #ff5733;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 80%;
  align-items: center;
  /*transform: translateX(100%);*/
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-links li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-links li a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  transition: 300ms;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav-links li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-links li {
  opacity: 1;
}

.burger {
  display: block;
}


@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}
section h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Section Images */
section#home {
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bZZp1PmHI0E/1600x900') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
section#portfolio {
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/VRxo0yY-gyM/1600x900') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
section#submit {
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/K2tdx2mFDHc/1600x900') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
section#contact {
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/2aAHlfDOhJM/1600x900') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
section#about {
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo+Black&family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Subworld Productions</title>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">-->


<body data-0="transform:translateX(0%)" data-4000="transform:translateX(-300%)">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <img src="Graphic logo.png" alt="Subworld Productions">
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#submit">Submit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section id="home">
      <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="portfolio">
      <h1>PORTFOLIO PAGE</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="submit">
      <h1>SUBMIT PAGE</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="contact">
      <h1>CONTACT PAGE</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="about">
      <h1>ABOUT PAGE</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
  </header>
  <!-- <script src="javascript/app.js"></script>
  <script src="skrollr.js"></script>-->
  <script src="http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/dist/skrollr.min.js">
    skrollr.init();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: An addendum: I'm not sure what you meant by diagonal scrolling? Usually pages vertically or horizontally? The snippet shows your nav horizontally.

Comment: Thanks for tidying it up for me! Yeah I made a pretty big mess there... and by diagonal scroll I meant literally, there's a plugin I used that made the page scroll down diagonally to the right, it looked pretty damn good, but I'll just give up on it. Thanks!!